# Хочу сделать interactive rebase но выдает ошибки, что я не так делаю?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

continue abort и skip не помогают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Когда начался процесс ребейза, нужно его завершить или отменить. В процессе ребейза не нужно больше ничего другого делать. Вы же пытаетесь делать merge и ещё один ребейз в процессе ребейза. Это почти всегда приведет к неведомым последствиям.

> > **Заархивируйте папку E:\Git, если что то пойдет не так, можно будет восстановить с архива (или дать архив "другу" на починку).**

Для начал я бы попытался удалить файл (или все таки каталог rebase-merge

```
rm -fr /E/Git/.git/rebase-merge
```

И скорее всего все заработает (хотя вполне возможно, ветки будут указывать "не туда").

Comment: Уже пробовал, к сожелению не удается решить проблему так. rm: cannot remove '/E/Git/.git/rebase-merge': Directory not empty

Comment: И добавили -rf или пропустили?

Comment: Просто скопировал ваше сообщение.

Comment: Тогда попытайтесь открыть в проводнике/far и удалить. Что то там с правами не то.